# Structure a nested json in dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, json, dataframe, pyspark, nested

I'm having some difficulty in structuring the following data, I would like the help of experts on this topic

I need to structure a json in dataframe in pyspark. I don't have its complete schema but it has this nested structure below that doesn't change:

```
import http.client conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("xxx")

payload = ""

conn.request("GET", "xxx", payload)

res = conn.getresponse() data = res.read().decode("utf-8")

json_obj = json.loads(data)

df = json.dumps(json_obj, indent=2)
```

This is the Json:

```
 {   "car": {
    "top1": {
      "cl": [
        {
          "nm": "Setor A",
          "prc": "40,00 %",
          "tv": [
            {
              "logo": "https://www.test.com/ddd.jpg",
              "nm": "BDFG",
              "lk1": "https://www.test.com/ddd/BDFG/",
              "lk2": "https://www.test-ddd.com",
              "dta": [
                {
                  "nm": "PA",
                  "cp": "nl",
                  "vl": "$ 2,50"
                },
                {
                  "nm": "FVP",
                  "cp": "UV",
                  "vl": "No"
                }
              ],
              "prc": "30,00 %"
            },
            {
              "logo": "https://www.test.com/ccc.jpg",
              "nome": "BDFH",
              "lk1": "https://www.test.com/ddd/BDFH/",
              "lk2": "https://www.test-ddd.com",
              "dta": [
                {
                  "nm": "PA",
                  "cp": "nl",
                  "vl": "$ 2,50"
                },
                {
                  "nm": "FVP",
                  "cp": "UV",
                  "vl": "No"
                }
              ],
              "prc": "70,00 %"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "nm": "B",
          "prc": "60,00 %",
          "tv": [
            {
              "logo": "https://www.test.com/bomm.jpg",
              "nm": "BOOM",
              "lk1": "https://www.test.com/ddd/BDFH/",
              "lk2": "https://www.test-ddd.com",
              "dta": [
                {
                  "nm": "PA",
                  "cp": "nl",
                  "vl": "$ 2,50"
                },
                {
                  "nm": "FVP",
                  "cp": "UV",
                  "vl": "No"
                }
              ],
              "prc": "100,00 %"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "top2": {
      "cl": [{}]
    "top3": {
      "cl": [{}]
     }
```

> Example of a json file

I tried to somehow structure my data but without success:

```
schema = StructType(
    [
      StructField("car", ArrayType(StructType([
        StructField("top1", ArrayType(StructType([
          StructField("cl", ArrayType(StructType([
            StructField("nm", StringType(),True),
            StructField("prc", StringType(),True),
            StructField("tv", ArrayType(StructType([
              StructField("logo", StringType(),True),
              StructField("nm", StringType(),True),
              StructField("lk1", StringType(),True),
              StructField("lk2", StringType(),True),
              StructField("dta", ArrayType(StructType([
                StructField("nm", StringType(),True),
                StructField("cp", StringType(),True),
                StructField("vl", StringType(),True)]))),
              StructField("prc", StringType(),True)])))])))]))),
        StructField("top2", ArrayType(StructType([
          StructField("cl", ArrayType(StructType([
            StructField("nm", StringType(),True),
            StructField("prc", StringType(),True),
            StructField("tv", ArrayType(StructType([
              StructField("logo", StringType(),True),
              StructField("nm", StringType(),True),
              StructField("lk1", StringType(),True),
              StructField("lk2", StringType(),True),
              StructField("dta", ArrayType(StructType([
                StructField("nm", StringType(),True),
                StructField("cp", StringType(),True),
                StructField("vl", StringType(),True)]))),
              StructField("prc", StringType(),True)])))])))]))),  
        StructField("top3", ArrayType(StructType([
          StructField("cl", ArrayType(StructType([
            StructField("nm", StringType(),True),
            StructField("prc", StringType(),True),
            StructField("tv", ArrayType(StructType([
              StructField("logo", StringType(),True),
              StructField("nm", StringType(),True),
              StructField("lk1", StringType(),True),
              StructField("lk2", StringType(),True),
              StructField("dta", ArrayType(StructType([
                StructField("nm", StringType(),True),
                StructField("cp", StringType(),True),
                StructField("vl", StringType(),True)]))),
              StructField("prc", StringType(),True)])))])))])))])))])


df2 = sqlContext.read.json(df, schema)
df2.printSchema()
```

I receive this message:
[image: error message]

i want to transform something like this:

[image: exemple of dataframe]

Is there any function that can facilitate this break and structure this data?

Comment: Side note: this is not JSON, this is a Python dict literal. It might be better if you run `print(json.dumps(..., indent=2))` to show data in true JSON format.

Comment: On topic: there is no single unambiguous way to represent this data in a 2-d table (i.e a data frame). Can you give an example of how you want it to be formatted?

Comment: @shadowtalker i edited the topic, tks!

Comment: your json is corrupted..check if the brackets are all balanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass JSON file path or RDD to json() method.

You need create RDD out of your JSON string using parallelize() then pass this RDD to json().

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([json.dumps(json_obj,indent=2)])
# Schema will be inferred automatically. You can pass schema if you want.
json_df = spark.read.json(rdd)
```